# Python, linked list

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list

Here is a question from leetcode:

> Define a function, input the head node of a linked list, invert the
> linked list.
>
> example:
>
> - input: `1->2->3->4->5->NULL`
> - output: `5->4->3->2->1->NULL`

Here is the official answer to it:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next

class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        cur , pre = head, None
        while cur:
            tmp = cur.next  
            cur.next = pre 
            pre = cur
            cur = tmp 
        return pre
```

I want to ask what does the line `while cur:` mean? Does it transverse the whole linked list? I tried to replace it with `while head:`, why it doesn't work since `cur == head`?

Comment: Because you change `cur` in the loop, you don't change `head`

Comment: `cur` is a pointer to the current node you are observing. See cur is being changed to `cur.next`. So when you will be at `tail` then `cur` will be `None`, so while loop will break.

Comment: Okay thanks. But how can I understand "while cur", does it same as "while cur ！= None"? I'm new to python and I found the syntax are bit different when dealing with linked list

Comment: As `cur` is either `None` or a `ListNode` object, and objects are truthy if used as a condition, and `None` is falsy if used as a condition, you can in this case write `while cur` as short for `while cur is not None`.

Answer (score 1):

```
while cur:
```

means

```
while cur is not None:
```

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: False, None, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true.

---

Now, your loop iterates over nodes of the input linked list and on the fly reverses the direction of "arrows" (pointers):

[image]
To reach this goal, in every iteration it at first saves the next-to-current node in the `temp` variable (`tmp = cur.next`) to make it current (`cur = tmp`) at the end of the loop — for the next iteration.

The 2 middle command change the direction of the arrow (`cur.next = pre`) — so the "next" will be the *previous* node — and prepare the `pre` variable (`pre = cur`) for the next iteration.

Comment: Nice picture. It reminds me a train with `None` as a locomotive. “Let's go back” — and the locomotive will relocate itself (through railroad switches) to the opposite side of the train to pull it in the reversed direction. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        cur , pre = head, None
        while cur:
            tmp = cur.next  
            cur.next = pre 
            pre = cur
            cur = tmp 
        return pre
```

Above is equivalent to:

```
class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        cur , pre = head, None
        while cur is not None:
            tmp = cur.next  
            cur.next = pre 
            pre = cur
            cur = tmp 
        return pre
```